# Clip corners of a tiled bitmap in a layer-list

Tags: android, android-resources, layer-list

I wish to accomplish something that looks like the bottom part of here (for all four corners, but I only have the bottom of the image to show you):

[image]

What I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/orange_tile"
            android:tileMode="repeat"
            android:dither="true"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="0.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

However, that gives me a *tiiiny* pixel in each corner, as per the preview:

[image]

So, how do I clip those corners? The visible stroke wasn't it and isn't actually desired...

---

Things tried:

Adding a solid to the items gives the perfect opposite of what I want. There may be a masking trick possible...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/orange_tile"
            android:tileMode="repeat"
            android:dither="true"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <color android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="0.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

---

The tile:

[image: A simple tile]

Comment: you want to clip/remove  orange image background? Right?

Comment: Can you also provide "orange_tile" drawables?

Comment: @jiteshmohite I want to remove the corners of the background tile

Comment: @jiteshmohite Added the tile

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few options.

1. Just add one more background rectangle to hide the corners:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item>
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/orange_tile"
           android:tileMode="repeat"
           android:dither="true"
           android:gravity="center" />
   </item>

   <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
           <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="0.5dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>

   <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
           <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="0.5dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>

   </layer-list>
   ```
2. You can move your corners rectangle out of the view and make it bigger:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item>
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_bg"
           android:tileMode="repeat"
           android:dither="true"
           android:gravity="center" />
   </item>

   <item android:top="-1.5dp" android:bottom="-1.5dp"
       android:left="-1.5dp" android:right="-1.5dp"
       >
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
           <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="1.5dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>

   </layer-list>
   ```

You'll need to fine-tune the offsets for this case. This one is a bit hacky, because it shrinks the tile content. You might want to scale the image with `android:scaleX="float"` and `android:scaleY="float"` when fine-tuning.

3. If you are open to code solution for getting rounded corners you can also try the [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html#setCornerRadius(float)) class.

   ```
   float cornerRadius = 2f * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;    

   Bitmap tileBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.orange_tile);
   RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedTileDrawable = 
       RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), tileBitmap);

   roundedTileDrawable.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
   ```

Comment: Won't option 3 round every tile though?

Comment: Options 1 and 2 have other side effects that break my (unpublished) requirements. You can't be blamed for that, that's totally on me.

Comment: I think you can use a bitmap based on a xml drawable of your tile with android:tileMode="repeat" in the 3rd approach.

Comment: I'm sorry for how improperly I've dealt with this. We're kinda deathmarching towards the end of the project and I couldn't fully validate this, and we also kinda changed the layout to circumvent the issue. I still felt you should be rewarded for your time and solution, but I've yet to try the final approach. Thank you.